# Set multiple values in yaml file, why got the first one only with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

Set this value in the settings.yml:

```
LIST: "a.net, b.com, c.org"
```

Get in the controller:

```
list = ENV["LIST"]
```

It returned `a.net` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you update the `settings.yml` file, you need to restart the `Rails` server to see the changes.

And you cannot update `environment` variables directly by updating `settings.yml` file.

The right way to access the value from `settings.yml` will be like this  (Assuming you are using [config](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) gem),

`list = Settings[:LIST]`

Comment: Thank you. But here not the gem issue, just want to get values in that yaml file from environment.